# Help regarding NER in NLTK

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

I have been working in NLTK for a while using Python. The problem I am facing is that their is no help available on training NER in NLTK with my custom data. They have used MaxEnt and trained it on ACE corpus. I have searched on the web a lot but I could not find any way that can be used to train NLTK's NER.

If anyone can provide me with any link/article/blog etc which can direct me to Training Datasets Format used in training NLTK's NER so I can prepare my Datasets on that particular format. And if I am directed to any link/article/blog etc which can help me TRAIN NLTK's NER for my own data.

This is a question widely searched and least answered. Might be helpful for someone in the future whose working with NER.

Comment: Cross-posted on https://www.quora.com/Help-on-training-NLTKs-NER

Answer (score 4):

Training a model, related to *information extraction*, in general, and *named entity recognition/resolution (NER)*, in particular, is described in detail in **Chapter 7** of the [NLTK Book](http://www.nltk.org/book), available online at this URL: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html.

Additionally, I think that you might find useful my [related answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136760/31372) on *Cross Validated* site. It has a lot of references to relevant *sources* on NER and related topics as well as to various related *software* tools.

Comment: They do not mention how to train the NER model on custom data, can you tell how to do it?

Comment: @HimaVarsha I'm not an expert in this area. However, ... I think that NLTK NER model comes pre-trained on the _conll2000_ corpus, hence no info in NLTK book. Check the following resources: 1. http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.io (most likely what you need; probably the _Training IOB Chunkers_ section). 2. http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2012/11/a-consumer-electronics-named-entity.html (might be useful as well). 3. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a (in case you use or will decide to use Stanford NER software).

Comment: I think stanfordcrf implementation does take custom data, but NTLK NER comes just pre-trained. The Training IOB Chunkers is just chunking right? Or does it even do NER?

Comment: @HimaVarsha Please pay more attention to advice you're getting. If you'd read post via link #2 above carefully, you'd see that the code there does both NER model training and running. I don't think I can help you beyond the advice above.

Answer (score 3):

Is this article good enough?
http://www.succeed-project.eu/wiki/index.php/NLTK#Input_format_for_training

There is explanation about how corpus should look like.

Your data needs to be in IOB format (word tag chunktag) to make it work.
Eric NNP B-PERSON
is VB O
the AT B-NP
CEO NN I-NP
of IN O
Google NNP B-ORGANIZATION

Comment: It would be ideal to post a short summary of the article in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial quite helpful: [Complete guide to build your own Named Entity Recognizer with Python](http://nlpforhackers.io/named-entity-extraction/)
He uses the Groningen Meaning Bank (GMB) corpus to train his NER chunk.

After that you can check this tutorial from the same person: [Training a NER System Using a Large Dataset](http://nlpforhackers.io/training-ner-large-dataset/) Where he uses scikit learn to improve the performance of his system.

Finally some really useful tutorials can be found here: [NLTK tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/tokenizing-words-sentences-nltk-tutorial/)
This guy has a youtube channel with a lot of tutorial in many subjects (ML,NLP, Python...)

Hope it helps.